# 18.04 Unversal access cursor size changes at will

Tags: 18.04, mouse

I used Universal Access to change cursor size to large but it never seemed to work right. If I'm on the desktop it is large, if I'm in an application, firefox, thunderbird, libre calc it will vary from default to large white, to what looks like an 'I' and very hard to see.  It seems like there must be a bad file or a conflict any idea how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem the 3.0 USB hub was stepping on the wifi trackball. The dealer on the hub warned me. I had the hub on the opposite side of the computer away from the wifi dongle, not good enough. Switched to a USB trackball problems gone.